# Reading config.json file in PHP

Tags: php, json, class, construct

I would like to ask what could be the problem with my code.

The situation is that I would like to read some data from a config.json file, and I have to use it in a class. My idea is to use a constructor function, but the script does not do anything with the values.

My code:

```
<?php

class test
{ 

private $json;
private $config;
private $xmlFiles;
private $modifiedElement;
private $modifiedElement2;
private $exchangeValue;
private $exchangeValue2;
private $inputFolderPath;
private $outputFolderPath;
private $outputFileName;


   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->setXmlFiles();
      $this->createFolder();
      $this->json = file_get_contents('config.json');
      $this->config = json_decode($json,true);
      $this->xmlFiles = array(); 
      $this->modifiedElement = $this->config->modifiedElement1; 
      $this->modifiedElement2 = $this->config->modifiedElement2; 
      $this->exchangeValue = $this->config->exchangeValue1; 
      $this->exchangeValue2 = $this->config->exchangeValue2; 
      $this->inputFolderPath = $this->config->inputFolderPath; 
      $this->outputFolderPath = $this->config->outputFolderPath; 
      $this->outputFileName = null; 

   }
```

On my **config.json** there are some test data:

```
{
  "modifiedElement1" : "11", 
  "modifiedElement2" : "22",
  "exchangeValue1" : "11",
  "exchangeValue2" : "333",
  "inputFolderPath" : "input/",
  "outputFolderPath" : "output/"
}
```

Can you help me with this?
I tried to declare the variables as public instead of private, did not work anyway unfortunately.

Comment: `json_decode($json,true);` where is `$json` defined?

Comment: Where are you defined variable `$json` ? You pass it as argument in `json_decode` but you must pass `$this->json`

Comment: @diegod at the same time :D

Comment: @Aro yes I saw :) by the way... the author of the question should break down its problem and address each part separately. Instead of throwing blindly the factory method at the problem, he should attempt to see if it can successfully accomplish the json decoding as the very first issue to address

Comment: "what can be the problem with my code" - what exactly is not working with the code? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: It looks obivous to me that the code does nothing. You don't instantiate your `test` class anywhere. Is this really the **whole** code you are currently using?

Answer (score 1):

The code has a couple of fairly low-level issues:

1. `$json` is not defined. You need to use `$this->json` since that's where you assigned the JSON data you read in from the file. This should be generating at least one warning in your code, but you didn't mention it - make sure you always have PHP error reporting switched on for debugging.
2. As per the [documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), the `true` argument you've passed to json_decode makes it returns an associative array instead of an object. Therefore the code later on trying to access it as if it's an object should generate some warnings/errors - but only if you first decode a variable which actually exists! Instead, you need to use `json_decode` without the `true` argument...and always read the manual!

Change

```
$this->config = json_decode($json,true);
```

to

```
$this->config = json_decode($this->json);
```

in order to resolve those two issues.

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/cfBos